# Change height button java code in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a square buttons in a fragment. My fragment layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_news"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_news_text"
        style="@style/buttons"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_insta"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_insta_text"
        style="@style/buttons"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I changed the height of buttons in `onCreateView`. This function implementation is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, container, false);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_menu, null);
    for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount();i++){
        View v=layout.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof ViewGroup){
            ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup)v;
            for(int j=0;j<vg.getChildCount();j++){
                View v2=vg.getChildAt(j);
                if(v2 instanceof Button){
                    Button btn=(Button)v2;
                    btn.setHeight(btn.getMeasuredWidth());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

I cannot change height of buttons in `onCreateView` and `getMeasuredWidth` function always returns 0.

How can I fix it?

Comment: is there are any special purpose to set the height from code? i think if you set it from the xml performance will be better

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715942/change-the-size-of-a-fragment-with-a-button

Comment: can i create square button in xml? i want to buttons width be half of screen width. @temnoi

Comment: @hamid yes. Just set layout_width and layout_height to the same value. if you want to have a specific layout with square buttons you can wrap them to another layout.

Comment: @hamid please check my example in answers. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this you can create a linear layout with wrap content dimension and add this button to that layout. Then set the Height of button and i think then, `getMeasuredWidth()` should not return 0.

This is my piece of code, you can customize it according to you

```
LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
newLL.setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
newLL.addView(btn);
widthSoFar = btn.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
```

[**Example here.**](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from XML

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="btn1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="btn2" />
</LinearLayout>
```